# Java java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java

Hola tengo un error en mi applet no se que sera, no me deja calcular el promedio.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Promedio2 extends Applet implements ActionListener {

  TextField tn1,tn2,tn3,tn4;
  Label n1,n2,n3,n4;
  Button boton;  
  double resultado;

    public Promedio2(){
     this.setLayout((null));

  n1= new Label("Numero 1: ");
  n1.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 20);
  n2= new Label("Numero 2: ");
  n2.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
  n3= new Label("Numero 3: ");
  n3.setBounds(20, 90, 100, 20);
  n4= new Label("Numero 4: ");
  n4.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);

  tn1 = new TextField();
  tn1.setBounds(120, 30, 100, 20);
  tn2 = new TextField();
  tn2.setBounds(120, 60, 100, 20);
  tn3 = new TextField();
  tn3.setBounds(120, 90, 100, 20);
  tn4 = new TextField();
  tn4.setBounds(120, 120, 100, 20);          

  boton = new Button("Calcular");
  boton.setBounds(120,180,100,20);

  add(n1);
  add(n2);
  add(n3);
  add(n4);
  add(tn1);
  add(tn2);
  add(tn3);
  add(tn4);
  add(boton);
  boton. addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics s){        
     this.setSize(500, 500);       

    s.drawString("Promedio = " +resultado,300, 200);  
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    int num1= Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
    int num2= Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
    int num3= Integer.parseInt(n3.getText());
    int num4= Integer.parseInt(n4.getText());
    resultado=num1+num2+num3+num4/4;
    repaint();

    }    
}
```

---

el error exactamente es este

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Numero 1: "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at modulo2.Promedio2.actionPerformed(Promedio2.java:62)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas referenciando los labels para obtener el valor de cada numero?
deberías acceder a tn1.getText() y así con los demás números, te da error por que estas obteniendo el valor de los labels que es un string y lo estas guardando en num1, num2, etc que son enteros.

En esta parte

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
int num1= Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
int num2= Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
int num3= Integer.parseInt(n3.getText());
int num4= Integer.parseInt(n4.getText());
resultado=num1+num2+num3+num4/4;
repaint();
```

deberías cambiar los n1, n2, etc. por los t1, t2, etc.

**PD: no pongas otra respuesta para poner la exception ponla en la pregunta**

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, que bruto de mi parte jajaja, es que soy nuevo en esto de applets.

Answer (score 0):

Te explicare lo que te han dicho ya pero con palabras diferentes:

En el siguiente segmento de código de tu programa intentas convertir cadenas a enteros, es decir, intentas convertir la palabra "Numero 1:" a un entero, lo cual es imposible.

 Al utilizar  "n1.getText()" estas obteniendo la cadena contenido en cada label (numero 1:, numero 2:, etc.)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
int num1= Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
int num2= Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
int num3= Integer.parseInt(n3.getText());
int num4= Integer.parseInt(n4.getText());
resultado=num1+num2+num3+num4/4;
repaint();

}
```